# Удаление пользователя по условию

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Как удалить пользователя по условию, если роль пользователя не равно 3?
Роли хранятся в отдельной таблице. При авторизации ID роли записывается в сессию. Не могу додуматься как правильно написать условие, то ли из-за того что два дня не спал(((

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequestID();
    $user = \R::load('users', $id);
    if ($_SESSION['user']['role_id'] == 3) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Нельзя удалить суперпользователя';
    } else {
        \R::trash($user);
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Пользователь удален';
    }
    redirect();
}
```

Comment: Вы бы указали, что за либу вы используете, какую ORM?

Comment: ORM - Redbean php

Comment: Можно использовать оператор `!==`